# How to use something similar to DynamicObject in Silverlight 3 / WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, dynamic-languages

How can you use Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) or something else to mimic System.Dynamic.DynamicObject in SILVERLIGHT 3 (!) and WP7 (no C# 4.0!)..

What I want to do is implement automatic dynamically created properties for databinding.

Comment: You mentioned data-binding, so just in case you didn't know this already: data-binding can't bind to dynamic objects in Silverlight even in Silverlight 4 with DynamicObject (or any other IDynamicMetaObjectProvider).  Only WPF 4 has that capability so far.

Answer (score 2):

The DLR can be used with WP7.
Iron Ruby supports Windows Phone 7 from [version 1.1](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/releases/view/43540#DownloadId=133276).

`DynamicObject` was available as an extension prior to .Net 4.0

If you're happy using a language other than C# then this could be an option.
There's a good article on using IronRuby on Windows Phone 7 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960707.aspx.

As an alternative, could you use anonymous types, rather than dynamic ones? I assume that there isn't an infinite number of options you're potentially binding to.

If you do want to use anonymous types you must set

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("System.Windows")]
```

to enable the framework to resolve the bindings.

Presumably you're getting you dynamic objects from an external system. Could you not add a wrapper layer between your app and the external system to turn the objects into POCOs rather than dynamic objects.

Comment: Why is DynamicObject available for Ruby but not for C# with the DLR?

Comment: @knom The IronRuby project includes a copy of `Microsoft.Scripting.Core` which contains `DynamicObject` You could try including a reference to this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, `DLR` with `.Net 4.0` and `C# 4.0` is not available in `WP7`. It means you can't do it. At least not easily.

Silverlight does not allow custom markup extensions (`things between {}`). So, that's not an option as well.

What you could do is create custom `Behaviors` for binding and make them work with `Dictionaries` that can hold as many properties and values.

Comment: This is the problem.. I know the solution with behaviors.. but I don't like it THAT much.. What about the Dynamic Language Runtime (dlr.codeplex.com), that DOES contain DynamicObject as well.. Does it work with SL3 ??