# Updating source code of an app directly from a link (patch) windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, code-behind

Is there a way to update the "source code" (code behind) on Windows Phone by downloading a file directly from the internet?

Comment: Yes kind of... not c# but you can use ironruby to do this. Please see this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603017/how-to-use-something-similar-to-dynamicobject-in-silverlight-3-wp7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to update the "source code" (code behind) on Windows Phone by downloading a file directly from the internet?

No. Apps are distributed in a XAP, and XAPs are signed. The "code-behind" gets compiled into an assembly anyway, so you would want to replace the assembly, not the code behind.

Regardless, Windows Phone 7 [explicitly disallows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326231/how-to-load-an-assembly-from-a-stream-or-byte-in-wp7/6326262#6326262) dynamic assembly loading from assemblies that are not part of the XAP.